# How to mimic `tikzpicture` inside `tikzpicture` (or how to fit `tikzpicture` into a node)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Also see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491850/141768).

---

I typeset my entire document inside a single `tikzpicture`, meaning that blocks of text in my document are represented by `\path node{...};`. But without using additional `tikzpicture` environment it gets complicated when a drawing has to be inserted into the document. Using additional `tikzpicture`, however, would create vertical spacing which is hard to deal with (and would ruin the frame box, aka `background rectange` around the `tikzpiture`). How do I get around this issue? Can we somehow use a scope and assign styles to it so that it can "mimic" `tikzpicture`? I need to be able to position and scale entire drawing easily, instead of dealing with each path of the drawing separately (to adjust it to the text above). It would also create problems with positioning text following the drawing, since the text needs to be aligned to something: you can't align nodes to paths which aren't nodes, and the drawing consists mostly of paths which aren't nodes (it would've been easy to position the text to a container of the drawing instead, but there's no such container).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm](n1){This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.};
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm]at(n1.south west){\[2+2=4\]};

    % following drawing should behave as a picture
    %  so that it can be easily moved and scaled
    \path node[anchor=north west](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
    \path[draw,radius=30pt]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,line width=1pt]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path node[font=\tiny]at($(t1.south)+(0,-40pt)$){text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following semi-works, but there are additional problems not highlighted in the output: (1) additional vertical spacing (which is fully under control if EVERYTHING is inside a single `tikzpicture`) due to second `tikzpicture` environment, (2) use of `varwidth` environment and (as a result) clipping of the nodes (on the right side).

```
\documentclass[varwidth=50mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm](n1){This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.};
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm]at(n1.south west){\[2+2=4\]};
  \end{tikzpicture}\par
  \begin{tikzpicture}[text width=50mm,align=center]
    \path node[anchor=north west](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
    \path[draw,radius=30pt]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,line width=1pt]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path node[font=\tiny]at($(t1.south)+(0,-40pt)$){text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{scope}[#scaling and positioning options]…\end{scope}`? That command can be well used for grouping related commands and sub-pictures

Comment: @Huang_d Sorry, didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You actually provided an answer, you deserve the credit. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you use a `scope` environment with the `local bounding box` option?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm](n1){This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.};
    \path node[anchor=north west,text width=50mm]at(n1.south west){\[2+2=4\]};

    % following drawing should behave as a picture
    %  so that it can be easily moved and scaled
    \begin{scope}[
       shift={(0,-3)},
       scale=0.7,
       local bounding box=smiley
       ]
    \path node[anchor=north west](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
    \path[draw,radius=30pt]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,radius=5pt]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
    \path[draw,line width=1pt]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \path node[font=\tiny]at($(t1.south)+(0,-40pt)$){text};
    \end{scope}

    \draw [red] (smiley.north west) to[bend left] (smiley.north east);

    \node [right] at (smiley.east) {foo};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]