# How to position `local bounding box` (scope containing a series of paths) below a node's `south` anchor?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

It's easy to position a node below a `local bounding box` (behavior is standard) but not the other way. I assume it's because the scope doesn't "know" about nodes outside of it. I tried to use `positioning` library to place the bounding box of the scope below the `south` anchor of one of the nodes above it, but no result. I also tried to select an anchor for the bounding box (`anchor=north`) but got same outcome (nothing).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n1)
      { This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
      };
    % DRAWING SHOULD BE POSITIONED BELOW FOLLOWING NODE (n2)
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n2)at(n1.south west)
      { \[2+2=4\]
      };
    % ------------- %
    % DRAWING BELOW %
    % ------------- %
    \begin{scope}
      [ scale=0.7,
        local bounding box=smiley
      ]
      \path node[anchor=north west](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=30pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          line width=1pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
      \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Adding `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in the preamble and `below=0mm of n2.south` in the square brackets (style) of the scope (node named "smiley", which is a `local bounding box`) doesn't work.

Use of `shift` is trial-and-error method, which is not a solution (we need `smiley`'s `north` anchor positioned exactly at `n2`'s `south` anchor).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[shift-(coordinate)]` to position the origin of a scope.  Then it is just a matter of positioning the contents of the scope relative to this origin.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n1)
      { This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
      };
    % DRAWING SHOULD BE POSITIONED BELOW FOLLOWING NODE (n2)
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n2)at(n1.south west)
      { \[2+2=4\]
      };
    % ------------- %
    % DRAWING BELOW %
    % ------------- %
    \begin{scope}
      [ shift=(n2.south),
        scale=0.7,
        local bounding box=smiley
      ]
      \path node[anchor=north](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=30pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          line width=1pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
      \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Or add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in the preamble and `below=0 of n2.south` to `t1`'s style. Idea is to have a "leading" node inside the scope and position rest of the paths/nodes in the scope relative to that node (so that entire drawing can be moved by altering that node's position).

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can (as of now) position local bounding boxes this way. However, you can declare the contents of your local bounding box a pic, this works (partly accidentally here, I have to add).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[smiley/.pic={code={
        \path node[anchor=north](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=30pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          line width=1pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
      \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
}}]
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n1)
      { This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
      };
    % DRAWING SHOULD BE POSITIONED BELOW FOLLOWING NODE (n2)
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n2)at(n1.south west)
      { \[2+2=4\]
      };
    % ------------- %
    % DRAWING BELOW %
    % ------------- %
    \pic[below=1ex of n2,scale=0.7] {smiley};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can use a `local bounding box` to position things relative to the pic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[smiley/.pic={code={
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
        \path node[anchor=north](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=30pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(-15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          radius=5pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(15pt,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$)circle;
      \path
        [ draw,
          line width=1pt
        ]($(t1.south)+(0,0)+(0,-30pt)$)--($(t1.south)+(0,10pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
      \path[draw]($(t1.south)+(-10pt,-15pt)+(0,-30pt)$)rectangle($(t1.south)+(10pt,-5pt)+(0,-30pt)$);
  \end{scope}     
}}]
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n1)
      { This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
      };
    % DRAWING SHOULD BE POSITIONED BELOW FOLLOWING NODE (n2)
    \path node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n2)at(n1.south west)
      { \[2+2=4\]
      };
    % ------------- %
    % DRAWING BELOW %
    % ------------- %
    \pic[below=1ex of n2,scale=0.7] {smiley=my smiley};
    \node[below=1ex of my smiley]{I am below my smiley};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the smiley is just a circle with some lines inside, you can draw it as a circular node with a `path picture`. This way you can place it with `positioning` library and avoid problems related to pics.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm
      ](n1)
      { This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.
      };
    % DRAWING SHOULD BE POSITIONED BELOW FOLLOWING NODE (n2)
    \node
      [ anchor=north west,
        text width=50mm,
        below= 5pt of n1
      ](n2)
      { \[2+2=4\]
      };
    % ------------- %
    % DRAWING BELOW %
    % ------------- %
    \begin{scope}
      [ scale=0.7, transform shape
      ]
      \node[below=5pt of n2](t1){DRAWING TITLE};
      \node[circle, minimum size=60pt, draw, below=5pt of t1,
        path picture={
            \draw (path picture bounding box.center)+(-15pt,10pt) circle (5pt);
            \draw (path picture bounding box.center)+(15pt,10pt) circle (5pt);
            \draw (path picture bounding box.center)--++(90:10pt);
            \draw (path picture bounding box.center)+(-10pt,-15pt) rectangle ++(10pt,-5pt);
        }
        ](smiley){};
    \end{scope}


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]